# Apache Ignite .Net CacheEvent

Tags: ignite

For example: I have two caches :A and B.
When I start event listening, I will listen for A and B's cached events, but I only want to listen for A's events. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CacheEvent` class has `CacheName` property, you can ignore events for irrelevant caches with that.

Alternatively, use [Continuous Queries](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries) to handle data changes on a per-cache basis.

Comment: This my Server Code.
`public class CacheEventListener : IEventListener<CacheEvent>
 {
        private readonly IMessaging messaging;

        public CacheEventListener(IMessaging messaging)
        {
            this.messaging = messaging;
        }
        public bool Invoke(CacheEvent evt)
        {
           if (evt.CacheName == "A")
            {
                    messaging.Send(evt, "Expired");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex, ex.Message);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }`

Comment: Hello, if I filter with CacheName, the client will only receive messages from caching A. Will this improve performance?Because the Ignite document says that using CacheEvent affects performance.[https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/local-and-remote-events#configuration]

Comment: Yes, this will improve performance - only matching events will be sent with messaging. Since you use `LocalListen`, this kind of filtering happens and the same node where the given key resides, so it is rather efficient.